# Добавить класс is_invalid к кастомным полям формы (input), а не к их оберткам в YII2

Tags: yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама форма выглядит так:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'contact',
    'validateOnBlur' => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'errorCssClass' => 'is-invalid',


    'options' => [
        'class' =>'form mt-5',


    ],
    'fieldConfig' => [
        //'options' => ['class' => 'form-group wrap-input100 validate-input'],
        'template' => "{input}{label}\n{hint}\n{error}",
        'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'symbol-input100'],
        'inputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control br-50 p-4']
    ],

]); ?>

<p class="title text-center">Оставить заявку на консультацию</p>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-column flex-md-row">
    <div class="form-group mr-md-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'name', ['errorOptions' => ['tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'text-danger']])->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Имя', ])->label(false) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-md-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'phone', ['errorOptions' => ['tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'text-danger']])->widget(MaskedInput::class,['mask' => '+7(999)-999-99-99'])->textInput()->label(false) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'title' )->hiddenInput(['value' => $this->title])->label(false) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg bg_dark_blue text-light br-50 btn-block', 'name' => 'contact-button']) ?>
<!--        --><?//= Html::a('Отправить', ['mailer'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg bg_dark_blue text-light br-50 btn-block']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

По этой теме, если ому интересно, то я победил. Сам получается затупил. Необходимо было подключить ActiveForm от bootstrap:

```
use \yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm;
```

Вместо:

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
```